# How to check if the VTCompressionSession is encoding the frame correctly

Tags: ios, macos, ios8, osx-yosemite, core-video

Is there any way to find out if the VTCompressionSession is compressing the images to h264 packets properly. I am checking the status code in the VTCompressionSession callback and it returns 0(Means no Error) but the packets which get broadcasted to the server appears blank.

Edit:- Found that VTCompressionSession callback function is showing the bufferData as empty on

```
  CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(block, 0, NULL, &size, &bufferData);
```

Any idea why it is happening ?

Comment: You can CFShow(sampleBuffer) or NSLog(@"%@", sampleBuffer) to display the contents of a sampleBuffer and all its properties. This will probably reveal more information about the issue. Note that both VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame and the callback function yield errors, so you need to check for both synchronous and asynchronous errors!